# Encryption needed for PouchDB on Cordova App for Android

Tags: android, database, cordova, encryption, pouchdb

I am developing an hybrid application using Cordova. We have to cache some sensitive data and we picked PouchDB.

The business came to us and asked if any external application would be able to read the DB. I know that for sure IOS has encryption in the cip but Android doesn't have it as far as I know.

So the question is: should I encrypt the database using a PouchDB plugin for encryption or it is not needed?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in a normal environment, apps are sandboxed and no other app has access to the local storage/db of your app.

Edit: As noted by Alex, if the device is rooted then it can be accessed. So, yes if your are using sensitive data, you should encrypt.

You can always check if the device has been rooted as well.

Alternatively, you can use [MongOGX](https://github.com/globules-io/MongOGX) which now supports encryption

Comment: ...unless device is rooted. So if your business data is really sensitive - encription is always good idea.